# Docusign Email Notifications

Tags: email, notifications, docusignapi

In my docusign account as shown below, I have only the option of where I only want to final, completed document sent to the sender as confirmation. However, I am still receiving all the emails like viewing and such and do not want those email. I just want the completed one. Is there a way to set this up in the API (xml) or in the Docusign account somewhere?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZdt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the admin setting.
Instead, go to https://appdemo.docusign.com/preferences/notifications to find your personal preferences (which you can also find from the top menu of web app, select "preferences"
and it should look like this:
[image]